# I cannot parse "country" and "name" with PARSE_JSON function in this very simple JSON object with SnowSQL

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-ingestion

I'm ingesting a large simple json dataset from Azure Blob and moving data into a "stage" called "cities_stage" with FILE_FORMAT = json like so.

(Here is the error steps are below "Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "Hurzuf", pos 7.")

```
create or replace stage cities_stage
url='azure://XXXXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/xxxx/landing/cities'
credentials=(azure_sas_token='?st=XXXXX&se=XXX&sp=racwdl&sv=XX&sr=c&sig=XXX')
FILE_FORMAT = (type = json);
```

I then take this stage location and dump it into a table with a single variant column like so. The file I'm ingesting is larger than 16mb so I create individual rows for each object by using type = json strip_outer_array = true

```
create or replace table cities_raw_source (
  src variant);

copy into cities_raw_source
  from @cities_stage
  file_format = (type = json strip_outer_array = true)
  on_error = continue;
```

When I **select * from cities_raw_source** each row looks like the following.

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lat": 44.549999,
    "lon": 34.283333
  },
  "country": "UA",
  "id": 707860,
  "name": "Hurzuf"
}
```

When I add a reference to "country" or "name" that's where the issues come in. Here is my query (I did not use country in this one but it produces the same result).

```
select parse_json(src:id),
  parse_json(src:coord:lat),
  parse_json(src:coord:lon),
  parse_json(src:name)
  from cities_raw_source;
```

ERROR:

**Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "Hurzuf", pos 7.**

ID, Lat, and Lon all come back as expected if I remove "src:name"

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had everything correct except for the query itself.

When querying a VARIANT column you do not need to PARSE_JSON so the correct query would look like this.

```
 select src:id,
  src:coord:lat,
  src:coord:lon,
  src:name
  from cities_raw_source;
```